# Edit Window stops displaying text after certain limit. (Windows)

Tags: c, windows, winapi, edit, autoscroll

I have developed a UDP Client Server Application in which Server Continuously reads data from 40 different Clients and displays it on a Edit Window. I have automatic Scroll enabled on mmy Edit Window as well.
My code is working fine and Server is continuously receiving data as well, but after displaying a certain amount of data on edit window, the Server stops displaying data. 
Apparently it looks like the Maximum Capacity of Edit Window is full, but I am not sure about why this is happening. 
Can anybody guide what might the problem be?
Is there any limit uptil which Edit Window can display data?
Waiting for help :(

Comment: Because it's full? IIRC, it has a limit of about 32K characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Standard Edit controls default to a max limit of 32767 characters.  Use the [`EM_LIMITTEXT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761607.aspx) message to set a different max limit as needed.

Comment: Is this possible that I set this limit to infinite? 
Since my application runs for an idefinite time period.

Comment: No, it cannot be set to infinite, but it can be set to 2GB, then highest value a 32-bit integer can hold. By the time you reach that many characters, you will need to start removing older characters to make room for newer characters. Or else re-think your UI design.

Comment: Any Idea about how can I start removing older characters?

Comment: Use `EM_SETSEL` to select the desired characters to remove, and then use `EM_REPLACESEL` with its `LPARAM` set to a blank string to remove those characters. If you want to remove entire lines, use `EM_LINEINDEX` and `EM_LINELENGTH` to calculate the values for `EM_SETSEL`.